# Elements of same additive order are associates in $\mathbb{Z}_m $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

The question is as in the title.

Are elements of same additive  order associate in $\mathbb{Z}_m $ ?

After looking for some examples like for $m=6,8,9 $ etc , it seems this statement is true. (I had in mind to avoid $m$ being prime since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field)

So I tried the proof like this.

From hereon , by order I would always mean additive order.

Attempt at a Proof:- Let $\mathbb{Z}_m$ be the given ring where $m \ge 4$

Now the set of units form a group $U$ (say) and they all have same order $(=m)$ and thus for two units $u$ and $v$ , there will be $x\in U$ such that $v=ux$

So the statement is true at least for units

Let me consider the set $A$ of all elements having a particular order $(\lt m)$

i.e $A=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}_m : ka=0\}$ where $k\lt m$

Let $u$ be a fixed unit and define a mapping

$f_u : A\to A$ by $f_u(a)=au$.

This is a well-defined map since $au\in A$

Let $f_u(a)=f_u(b) $

$\Rightarrow au=bu$

$\Rightarrow a=b$ (By right cancellation)

So $f_u$ is injective and since $A$ is finite , $f_u$ is surjective.

So for every $b \in A$ , there is $a\in A$ such that $au=b$

Aha ! I have proved the other way that for an element $b$ of some order and given a unit $u$, there exists an $a$ of the same order as $b$ such thaf $b=au$

Do you have any suggestions ? Thanks for your attention and time.

Comment: As for the original question, yes, $f_u$ acts as permutations on $A$, as you have proved. Why does the group of units act transitively on $A$ though?

Comment: @David Craven: I think I messed up  – I was doing two things at the same time when I posted this comment. I'll delete it

Comment: You have noted that units are associate. I haven't checked this will work, but have you tried using a different ring ($\mathbb{Z}_n$ for $n<m$) to find a unit associating your two elements, and then lifting?

Comment: @DavidCraven. Sorry for late response, sir. As you have correctly pointed out, the action has to be transitive which I am unsure of .Do you have any idea? For your second comment ,  I did not understand it. Can you please explain, especially the lifting ?

Comment: For transitivity I would count the size of the stabilizer of an element, then use the formula for $\phi(n)$ and $\phi(m)$ when $n\mid m$. For the second comment, if $a$ has order $n<m$, and $m/n=d$, then $a=d.a'$ for some $a'$, and $a'$ should be a unit in a different ring, I guess $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Solve the problem there and then try to lift the result back to $\mathbb{Z}_m$. I haven't checked if this works, as I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ have the same additive order, that means that the (unique) smallest $z$ such that $xz = 0$ is the same as that for $y$. This simply means that the $\gcd(x,m) = \gcd(y,m)$, and $z=\frac m{\gcd(x,m)}$. Now, let $x'=\frac x{\gcd(x,m)}$, $y'=\frac y{\gcd(y,m)}$, and $m'=\frac m{\gcd(x,m)}$. Then $\gcd(x',m')=\gcd(y',m')=1$, so in $\mathbb Z_{m'}$ there is an $a$ such that $ax'=y'$. Working in $\mathbb Z$, this means that
$$ax' = y'+km'$$
Multiplying by $\gcd(x,m)$ we get
$$ax = y+km$$
so $ax=y$ in $\mathbb Z_m$, and the result follows.

Comment: Is existence of unit $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{m'}$ confirmed by the fact that $x'$ and $y'$ are units in $\mathbb{Z}_{m'}$  ? Please clarify this ,sir .

Comment: @user710290 Yes, this is asserted in $\gcd(x',m')=\gcd(y',m')=1$.